# Turning off the event handlers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a paint application. Here is a function to free drawing on the canvas. How can I turn off the event handlers in this particular when I move to the next tool. So that it will not cause any conflict with other functions.

```
function free(){
  var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
  var radius=10;
  var dragging1=false;


context.lineWidth=2*radius;

var putPoint=function(e) {
if(dragging1){
  context.lineTo(e.clientX,e.clientY);
  context.stroke();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(e.clientX,e.clientY,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
  context.fill();
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(e.clientX,e.clientY);
 }//end of if
}

var engage = function(e) {
  dragging1=true;
  putPoint(e);
}

var disengage = function() {
  dragging1=false;
  context.beginPath();
}
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',disengage);
}
```

Comment: not an answer - you `beginPath` twice in `putPoint`, and again in `disengage` but you never `endPath` ... that looks incorrect

Comment: will **removeeventlistener** not solve your purpose?

Comment: you can add conditionals to your handlers so they don't run when the mode is wrong. alternatively, and perhaps better, your handlers can simply check and respond appropriately to current state.

Comment: @AnkushRaghuvanshi probably not - managing and rotating listeners is likely more fragile and unclear than making the relevant listeners select and perform functionality based on current mode.

Comment: @pvg when another button gets clicked how can i manage this event listener

Comment: @Ananthu the caller/source of the listener invocation is referenced in the event the listener receives.

Comment: What about a single listener that delegates to the correct function depending on the currently selected tool?

Comment: how can i do that?